# Need string formation with space in php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
$string='to kill a mocking bird';
```

Need output like below format

**Output:**

> '"To kill a mocking bird",
>   "Tokill a mocking bird",
>   "Tokilla mocking bird",
>   "Tokillamocking bird",
>   "Tokillamockingbird",
>   ,"To kill a mockingbird"
>   ,"To kill amockingbird"
>   ,"To killamockingbird"';
>
> **I used below Script**

```
$array = is_string($arg) ? str_split($arg) : $arg;

if(1 === count($array))
  return $array;


  $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $item)
        foreach(permute(array_diff_key($array, array($key => $item))) as $p)
            $result[] = $item .' '. $p;
    return $result;
```

Comment: What do you have so far and what is the problem with it exactly?

Comment: I bet you have already tried something. Right?

Comment: I need to search above phrases using match against with different formations of text...for that i need it

Comment: Hi andreas ...i tried and need more help

Comment: you can use like query in database

Comment: It will take more time..

Comment: We don't want to know that you have tried, we want to know **what** you have tried.

Comment: I tried to execute above format upto my level...but i didn't get proper output...

Comment: Again... We need to know what you have tried. Edit your question and add the code you have tried to create the output you want. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I have a done code here for you. Just add your attempts and I will post an answer. http://forumbilder.se/GAFE7/img-20171207-110550

Comment: I edited my code...check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use explode to make it an array that I can loop through.
In the loop I use implode to add space and array_slice to select the corresponding words to join/add space between.
I loop once forward and once backwards to get all combinations.

```
$str='to kill a mocking bird';

$arr = explode(" ", $str);
Echo $str."\n";

For($i=1;$i<count($arr);$i++){
    Echo implode("", array_slice($arr, 0,$i)) . implode(" ", array_slice($arr, $i)) . "\n";
}

For($i=count($arr)-1;$i>1;$i--){
     Echo implode(" ", array_slice($arr, 0, $i)) . implode("", array_slice($arr,$i, count($arr))) . "\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/QVIKG