# PHP - How to make all combination from user input from all to 1 word

Tags: php

If I have a string $input and explode it into an array like this, then $arr should contain each of the four words

```
$input = "hello everybody at here";
$arr = explode(" ",$input);
```

But I would like to get all combination possibilities, like this:

> hello everybody at here 
>  hello everybody at
>  hello
>   everybody
>  hello
>  everybody at here
>  etc

How can I do this? :D

Thanks

Comment: You can loop through the array two times: One time backwards and one time forwards. Go ahead and think of how that would help you solve your problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need string formation with space in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691979/need-string-formation-with-space-in-php)

Comment: andreas: no i don't think so

Comment: Sorry, I linked to the wrong thread

Comment: Think about a 4-bits binary number, `0000` to `1111`, `0` is hidden, `1` is shown, ie counting from 1 to 15 in your case...

Comment: Why is this thread upvoted? There is no attempts at all

Comment: hi, anyone have code for this case :D

Comment: Do you want all possible combinations (like https://pastebin.com/kCNMsrLa ), or do you want to keep words' position order?

Comment: This post will point you in the right direction - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to get all possible combinations of 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array)

Answer (score 0):

***You can check this: (using a recursive function)***

```
$input = "hello everybody at here";
$array = explode(" ",$input);

function permutation($arr, $ts, &$newArray)
{
    if ($ts != "")
        $newArray[] = $ts;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $temp = $arr;
        $elem = array_splice($temp, $i, 1);
        if (count($temp) > 0) {
            permutation($temp, $ts . " " . $elem[0], $newArray);
        } else {
            $newArray[] = $ts . " " . $elem[0];
        }
    }
}

$newArray = [];
permutation($array, "", $newArray);
print_r($newArray);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/OP5XD